# When running on a server I get a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' In Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-8

So I am making an application and I am pushing it onto a server but when I do, the page displays only HTML. Upon checking the console, it appears to give a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for a whole bunch of my CSS and JS files... I'm not so clued up with stuff being hosted on a server but the program works fine locally and read all the file as it should from the paths, which is in the public/assets folder.

Do you guys know what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: While you need to upload your entire folder structure to the server, you then need to set up your domain to point inside your public folder. It's probably pointing to `/` right now, which doesn't contain any website files. Point it to `/public/` instead, where `index.php` is located.

Comment: How would I set everything to read from the public folder? I was thinking of editing my view pages

Comment: No, you need to log into your hosting's admin area and go to domain setup, then change the internal redirect.

Comment: okay, do you have any materials I could read on? im not really following

Comment: You say you're "pushing it onto a server". How did you do that? Via FTP upload? Where did you purchase your hosting plan?

Comment: I putting it on for a friend. so we have uploaded all the files to a server and linking its with something like 153.0.251.0/app

Comment: Ok, if you just see HTML but the stylesheets aren't loaded, you need to check the paths. Look at the source (Ctrl+U) and click the underlined `href` value of a stylesheet. Compare the resulting URL to the actual location.

Comment: @ChrisG okay so on the crtl u side, `../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` shows and the actual path is `appname\public\assets\css\bootstrap.min.css`